# WPF application has encountered a problem and needs to close, how to get good message?

Tags: c#, wpf, crash

I am currently working on a WPF application that processes data in a database and it worked fine when I tested it with a test database with around 1000 rows but now I want to process around 50 000 rows and it just crashes during the processing giving me "'application' has encountered a problem and needs to close ... Do you want to send error report to Microsoft...".

Now this may seem like a duplicate of a couple of other questions but I've tried AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException, AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit, Application.DispatcherUnhandledException and it just crashes with no message anyway.

Here's what it looks like:

```
private void OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
  AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += (s, args) =>
  {
    MessageBox.Show("Message1");
  };

  AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit += (s, args) =>
  {
    MessageBox.Show("Message2");
  };

  this.DispatcherUnhandledException += (s, args) =>
  {
    MessageBox.Show("Message3");
  };

  try
  {
    Views.MainView view = new Views.MainView();
    view.DataContext = new ViewModels.MainViewModel();
    view.ShowDialog();
  }
  catch (Exception exception)
  {
    MessageBox.Show(exception.ToString());
  }
}
```

The processing is started by a command (a GUI button with command binding to call this):

```
public void Process()
{
  Thread workerThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(DoProcess));
  workerThread.IsBackground = true;
  workerThread.Start();
}

private void DoProcess()
{
  try
  {
    // Most probably crashes during that
    DoStuff();
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
  }
}
```

I checked the memory usage during execution and it never goes above 70 meg, so that shouldn't be a problem. I use 2 COM components, one that is an .exe and another that is a .dll, I don't know if problems can come from that. Note that sometimes those components crash and I do receive a useful error message when it happens. I work with NHibernate to read/write from the database.

For now I have absolutely no clue what the problem is (the DoStuff() part is quite big), and I don't understand how an error can get past all those exception handlers and just crash the application without information. Note that I can't debug the application in Visual Studio because I run the application on a VM that doesn't have Visual Studio installed (and I've been waiting for 2 months to get my IT department to install me sql server so that I can run my application on my computer).

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DoProcess function is in a background thread.  Another thread may be crashing, or you might have an issue calling MessageBox from a background thread because it's not the UI thread -- so you may be getting an exception, and then a new exception is thrown from your catch because of the MessageBox call.  Try inserting code to write the message to a file before the MessageBox call and see if that works, or even a Console.Beep() for that matter and listen for it :-)  If that uncovers nothing, try adding log statements to files at many places in your code until you narrow down where the crash occurs.

Comment: It didn't work. I just tried writing File.Create("C:\\dumpFile.txt") instead of the MessageBox.Show, but still the file wasn't created and I still got an application crash.

Comment: That probably means another thread is crashing, which is why your catch doesn't work.  Add logging code to your app to narrow where the crash is.

Comment: Yeah I think I'll go with the logging approach, but is it possible to set an event handler or otherwise catch an error on another thread? Note that my DoStuff method doesn't create any other thread, at least in the parts that I've written (I don't know if NHibernate or .NET's COM wrappers create threads).

Comment: I know of no way to catch all errors in threads. One issue could be that you are exceptioning in the COM (unmanaged) code in which case no C# catch of any kind would apply and you would crash out like you are.  Check your COM calls.

Comment: All my COM methods are wrapped into try/catch blocks to avoid failures there, and note that if a COM call fails (even if the COM process completely crashes and exits), I get an exception on the C# side. This might very well be a threading issue, but I think it's not a COM problem.

Comment: Certain kinds of unmanaged exceptions are not caught in managed code.  You can trust me on that -- it has happened.

Comment: Well it seems you are right. It seems to come from my COM component, because the call sometimes fail I had added a retry to make sure the error isn't due to some timeout or something (I really don't know much about COM). It seems when it fails the first time I can catch the exception, but when it fails the second time the same catch clause doesn't catch it. So I guess if it fails I'll just report it to the user and don't try a second time.

Answer (score 0):

You really need to get Visual Studio and the debugger set up.  You'll be probing in the dark without it.

Comment: Yeah that's the best option, but I was wondering if there was a way to catch the error in the code?

Comment: In Visual Studio you can have the debugger break at the line where the exception is thrown rather than where it is caught

Comment: @Carl, perhaps you can get them to build you a VM with Visual Studio?

Comment: @Scott, believe me if I can do something without asking our IT department for anything it will take less time this way.